# Swift: Crash app if use DropDown()

Tags: ios, swift, dropdown

I use this code :

```
let amountDropDown = DropDown()
amountDropDown.anchorView = view
amountDropDown.dataSource = ["Car", "Motorcycle", "Truck"]
```

After i lunch app, my app crashed :

```
2018-05-12 17:45:18.946508+0430 Matap[47483:593732] Unknown class _TtC13DropDown_Demo12DropDownCell in Interface Builder file.
2018-05-12 17:45:18.965499+0430 Matap[47483:593732] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIView 0x7f9001d38760> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key optionLabel.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e19612b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010d82af41 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e196079 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010d249a63 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 292
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010f097288 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) setValue:forKey:] + 172
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010f457c2d -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e1393cd -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 317
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010f4565e3 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1856
    8   Matap                               0x000000010cea3e51 _T08DropDownAAC12fittingWidth33_7BE2DBF176694C4708972467648CE159LL12CoreGraphics7CGFloatVyF + 785
    9   Matap                               0x000000010cea67e8 _T08DropDownAAC39constraintWidthToFittingSizeIfNecessary33_7BE2DBF176694C4708972467648CE159LLy12CoreGraphics7CGFloatV1x_AG1yAG5widthAG15offscreenHeighttz6layout_tF + 216
    10  Matap                               0x000000010cea2d3b _T08DropDownAAC13computeLayout33_7BE2DBF176694C4708972467648CE159LL12CoreGraphics7CGFloatV1x_AG1yAG5widthAG15offscreenHeightAG07visibleN0Sb14canBeDisplayedAB9DirectionOANtyF + 2651
    11  Matap                               0x000000010cea08e7 _T08DropDownAAC17updateConstraintsyyF + 215
    12  Matap                               0x000000010cea3554 _T08DropDownAAC17updateConstraintsyyFTo + 36
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010fb46878 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _sendUpdateConstraintsIfNecessaryForSecondPass:] + 161
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010fb46e94 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededCollectingViews:forSecondPass:] + 1296
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010fb476c5 __100-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededWithViewForVariableChangeNotifications:]_block_invoke + 90
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010fb47234 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededWithViewForVariableChangeNotifications:] + 160
    17  Matap                               0x000000010ce9fa6b _T08DropDownAAC5setup33_7BE2DBF176694C4708972467648CE159LLyyFyycfU_ + 43
    18  Matap                               0x000000010ceb10d2 _T08DropDownAAC5setup33_7BE2DBF176694C4708972467648CE159LLyyFyycfU_TA + 50
    19  Matap                               0x000000010ce6e2c9 _T0Ix_IyB_TR + 41
    20  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000112ff12f7 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    21  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000112ff233d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    22  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000112ffd5f9 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 628
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e158e39 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e11d462 __CFRunLoopRun + 2402
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e11c889 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
    26  GraphicsServices                    0x000000011538b9c6 GSEventRunModal + 62
    27  UIKit                               0x000000010efc65d6 UIApplicationMain + 159
    28  Matap                               0x000000010ce83fa7 main + 55
    29  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000011306ed81 start + 1
    30  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I think reason of crash is this line : `let amountDropDown = DropDown()`

Also, I `import DropDown` into my swift code

This Plugin: [DropDown](http://%20https://github.com/AssistoLab/DropDown)

Codes:

```
import UIKit
import DropDown

class ViewControllerHandle: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var viewMain: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var backBoard: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondGo: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var thirdGo: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var firstGo: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var goToSecond: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var firstView: UIView!

    /* BOX GENDER */
    @IBOutlet weak var boxGender: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var genderSelect: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var pickerGender: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var textPickerGender: UILabel!

    /* BOX EX */
    @IBOutlet weak var boxEx: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var exSelect: UIView!

    /* BOX EMERGENCY */
    @IBOutlet weak var boxEmergency: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var emergencySelect: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let backBoardGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleBackBoard(sender:)))
        backBoard.addGestureRecognizer(backBoardGesture)

        let goToSecondGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleGoToSecond(sender:)))
        goToSecond.addGestureRecognizer(goToSecondGesture)

        let setBG = SetBackground()
        setBG.addGradient(viewMain: viewMain)

        secondGo.layer.cornerRadius = 45
        thirdGo.layer.cornerRadius = 45
        firstGo.layer.cornerRadius = 45
        goToSecond.layer.cornerRadius = 20

        boxGender.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        genderSelect.layer.cornerRadius = 20

        boxEx.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        exSelect.layer.cornerRadius = 20

        boxEmergency.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        emergencySelect.layer.cornerRadius = 20

        let amountDropDown = DropDown()
    }

    @objc func handleGoToSecond(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let homeViewController: UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerMenu")
        self.present(homeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @objc func handleBackBoard(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you install this library?

Comment: What is view? If you show all the code from this method you will make it easier for others to help you

Comment: your app Terminated because  this label `optionLabel` Please check this label `Outlet`

Comment: @arturdev via podfile

Comment: @a.masri i'm sorry. can you explain more ?

Comment: @Mohammad , Ok go to your storyboard  and check this `optionLabel` Outlet

Comment: @a.masri i cant find optionLabel, where is it ? thx

Comment: @Mohammad same this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/50314529/9315978

Comment: do you use DropDown version 2.0.1 ??

Comment: @a.masri i don't know. i just added pod 'DropDwon'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had an outlet of `UILabel` in your view controller file. as:

```
@IBOutlet weak var optionLabel: UILabel!
```

You removed the line from code, but reference is still available on the `UIStoryboard`, that why are receiving error:

> **this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key optionLabel.**

To resolve this, follow following steps:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, i removed optionLabel but not work.

Comment: Are you getting same error? and are you following [link](https://github.com/AssistoLab/DropDown#custom-cell) for cell?

Comment: Yes. I dont want use custom cell. if i use let amountDropDown = DropDown() crashed app. if i commented //let amountDropDown = DropDown(), app work as fine

Comment: Well @Mohammad, I just tried adding library in code at my end & it worked fine. No need of any connection anywhere, just wrote above 3 lines you shared and called it as `amountDropDown.show()`.

Comment: If you removed the false reference and not using custom cell then the error `class is not key value coding-compliant` won't appear.

Comment: I edit my post and added codes. please check it

Answer (score 2):

Did you create Custom Cell which is subclass of `DropDownCell`?
If so, this link is maybe helpful: https://github.com/AssistoLab/DropDown#custom-cell

`optionLabel` is a property of DropDownCell.

```
open class DropDownCell: UITableViewCell {

    //UI
    @IBOutlet open weak var optionLabel: UILabel!

    var selectedBackgroundColor: UIColor?
}
```

ReadMe in tne link says:

> At least have a label in your xib to link to the optionLabel IBOutlet in code (optionLabel is a property of DropDownCell)